# What is the best format to save an image in Python, and why does pydot save invalid images?

Tags: python, image

I am using `pydot` to save an image file on my machine and then use the Image module to open the file. However, I get an error using `Windows Photo viewer`. The image cannot be opened because it is deleted or is in unavailable location. This is incorrect as the image gets saved to my Desktop.

Sometimes, randomly, the picture does gets opened, but takes a lot of time.  Why am I getting this problem?

I have an option to save the image in any format. Is there an image format that one could save that would take comparatively less time opening via Python, or do all formats take the same time?

Comment: Well, what format do you save it in now? But in general, I wouldn't give a damn about Windows Photo Viewer, if only for the fact that I was never able to use it with any image (perhaps jpg is too fancy?)

Comment: Currently I am saving it as .png .....

Comment: What format are you saving the image in? (I would try PNG or JPG format.) And concerning the Windows Photo Viewer error: Are you using any special characters to name the file or in its path? Are you sure the image is not corrupt?

Comment: @scoffey I said that I am saving it as .png ....... Nopes I am saving the file as example.png and I can go and open the file seperately if I wish..... it just does'nt open when the program is running....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like a known bug in the image viewer of PIL on Windows Vista/7. You can try to fix PIL/ImageShow.py as follows:

```
diff -r 142e08f1b589 PIL/ImageShow.py
--- a/PIL/ImageShow.py  Sun Aug 01 22:00:26 2010 +0200
+++ b/PIL/ImageShow.py  Wed Jan 05 10:46:47 2011 -0800
@@ -97,7 +97,7 @@
     class WindowsViewer(Viewer):
         format = "BMP"
         def get_command(self, file, **options):
-            return "start /wait %s && del /f %s" % (file, file)
+            return "start /wait %s && ping -n 2 127.0.0.1 >NUL && del /f %s" % (file, file)

     register(WindowsViewer)
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked for me.  I shudder to be working on windows 7.