# Image is not displaying in Google Colab while using imshow()

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib, google-colaboratory, imshow

I am working on a project which requires functions from OpenCV to plot images.
I am trying to display image using the below code in Google Colab. But nothing shows up in the output. Can anybody help me with this?

```
%pylab notebook
import cv2

testim = imread('butterfly.jpg')
figure()
imshow(testim)
plt.show()
```

Screenshot:

[image]

[Link to my Colab Notebook](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1CKPbf1zAOk8OGBQ3C_wkQ8lNwbHoBDnA)

Comment: Found one workaround. We can use `%matplotlib inline` in the code to use [tag:imshow]. Used as example here in In[28] - [Colab notebook git](https://github.com/alankritmishra/DL-CompVisionNotebooks/blob/master/Packt_CV_w_Python3_Getting_Started_with_Jupyter_notebooks_Done.ipynb)

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Google colab crashes if you try to display image using `cv2.imshow()` instead import `from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow` and display using `cv2_imshow(<image>)`

Comment: Works like a charm. It takes only one argument, the file itself.

Answer (score 16):

The cv2.imshow() and cv.imshow() functions from the opencv-python package are incompatible with Jupyter notebook; see https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/3935.

As a replacement, you can use the following function:

```
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow
```

For example, here we download and display a PNG image of the Colab logo:

```
!curl -o logo.png https://colab.research.google.com/img/colab_favicon_256px.png
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('logo.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
cv2_imshow(img)
```

Credits: Code Snippets in Google Colab

Answer (score 11):

Found one workaround. We can use `%matplotlib inline` in the code to use [imshow](/questions/tagged/imshow). Used as example here in In[28] - [link](https://github.com/alankritmishra/DL-CompVisionNotebooks/blob/master/Packt_CV_w_Python3_Getting_Started_with_Jupyter_notebooks_Done.ipynb)

Comment: that's imshow by matplotlib, not by opencv

Answer (score 3):

`imshow` requires an X server, which isn't available in a web browser.

Instead, use the `IPython.display.Image` library. Here's an example:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1jWHKR6rhhyZtUulttBD6Pxd_AJhgtVaV
[image]

Comment: Hi Bob, I need to use `imshow()` to plot images with different OpenCV functions. Is there any workaround to use it in Colab?

Comment: I'd recommend asking a distinct question that describes the precise scenario requiring `imshow`. It will be a terrific pain to start an X server and pipe a snapshot from its rendered output, but it's doable. I suspect it will be worth considering alternatives.

Comment: Found one workaround. We can use `%matplotlib inline` in the code to use [tag:imshow]. Used as example here in In[28] - [link](https://github.com/alankritmishra/DL-CompVisionNotebooks/blob/master/Packt_CV_w_Python3_Getting_Started_with_Jupyter_notebooks_Done.ipynb)

Answer (score 1):

```
cv2.imshow()
```

does not work well in colab, you can use `matplotlib` for displaying.

```
import matplotlib.image as mpimg 
from matplotlib.pyplot import imshow
%matplotlib inline
testim = mpimg.imread('butterfly.jpg')
imshow(testim)
```

or you can do colab's own `cv2_imshow` version

```
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow
cv2_imshow('butterfly.jpg')
```

Answer (score 1):

I am also facing a same issue in google colab.

We can use cv2_imshow() instead of (cv2.imshow or cv.imshow):

```
#We must import first line of code
**#working module**

from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow
import cv2 as cv
#Replace cv2.imshow() to cv2_imshow()
img = cv.imread('python.jpg') #mentioning a path of an image
cv2_imshow(img)
```

while we are using our local machine to visble any image then we use this code **cv.imshow()**, but when it comes to google colab we should switch to alternative code **cv2_imshow()**

[image: example]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `cv2.imshow()` try this:

1. Change the import to `from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow`
2. Replace `cv2.imshow()` to `cv2_imshow()`

I tried it and it worked for me.