# !_img.empty() in function 'imwrite'

Tags: opencv, google-colaboratory

i just try this code in colab google

```
for label in labels:
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
print('Collecting images for {}'.format(label))
time.sleep(5)
for imgnum in range(number_imgs):
    print('Collecting image {}'.format(imgnum))
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    imgname = os.path.join(IMAGES_PATH,label,label+'.'+'{}.jpg'.format(str(uuid.uuid1())))
    cv2.imwrite(imgname, frame)
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
    time.sleep(2)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
```

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
and i got this erreur

Comment: Which camera do you expect to capture in colab? img.empty() means there was no image successfully captured, better test whether ret is true.

Answer (score 3):

There are no webcams on Google Colab servers.

Code on Google Colab is running on google servers, not in your browser.

You can't open `VideoCapture(0)` when you run code on Google Colab.

You need to have error checking in your code for VideoCapture.

Since you don't check for errors, and opening the VideoCapture failed, `frame` will be `None`. You can't `imwrite` `None` because that's not a valid array/image.

```py
...
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
assert cap.isOpened() # THIS

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if not ret: break # AND THIS
...
```

Comment: a question written about colab this code will not work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57651882/10850556 this link will help you

Comment: I try it but it still the  same error

Comment: I repeat, `frame` is empty, you can't `imwrite` an empty frame. it's empty because there are no webcams on google colab. I can't state this any plainer. -- ignore Ali and his link. he doesn't realize what the problem is.