# Image is not displaying in Google Colab while taking input after imshow

Tags: python-imaging-library, imshow

I want to read an image from folder and display then from user input insert some details in dataframe. I need to loop 1000 images for annotation but i only see input not the image
'''
img =Image('/content/drive/MyDrive/dataset/images/01.jpg',cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
cv2_imshow(img)
id = input("Enter id ")
'''

Comment: attach the screenshot of your code snippet and output, then it will be helpful to get your problem.

Comment: you can try matplotlib.inline magic function at the top of notebook

%matplotlib inline

Answer (score 0):

Google colab crashes if you try to display image using cv2.imshow() instead import from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow and display using cv2_imshow()

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57651882/12606908

Comment: Yes this too didn't work