# 'module' object is not callable while opening a image in python using PIL

Tags: python, image, jupyter-notebook, ipython, python-imaging-library

I want to open image in python.I have been using PIL for opening the image but it throw 'module' error is not callable

```
import PIL
from PIL import Image

image=Image.open(r'C:\Users\intel\Downloads\11fcf12ff3cf97e8e7a88f3e485255e6.jpg')
print(image)

display(image)       #the error is thrown here
```

Comment: what's `display`? where is it defined?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to show PIL images on the screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12570859/how-to-show-pil-images-on-the-screen)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want to use display? What would you like accomplished? Maybe show... There is a method like show() in PIL library so in your case it would be image.show()

Comment: show() wont open the image in jupiter notebook. It would rather open the image in new window using native app

Comment: then you need to use IPython module