# Image.open doesn't show any results

Tags: python, image, debugging, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to display an image using python. I used the following code :

```
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open("pic.jpg")
img.show()
del img
```

I checked that everything was installed, and tried different options inside the Image.open part, yet nothing works. I don't even have an error (so other topics were irrelevant in my case).

I am new to python, so I have no idea how to debug this. My code just executes but nothing happens.

If you have an idea, I'll try. Thank you.

Comment: @Suvo: What you say is untrue. Try it. The script works fine for me so the problem must be something else. The [documenation](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.show) says that the `show()` method creates a temporary file and invokes an OS-dependent utility to display it, so deleting the in-memory image data doesn't affect that.

Comment: Eltom: Have you tried different images & image types?

Comment: 1) Please state your OS and how you ran the script 2) please add `print(img)` after you open it so we can see its dimensions and type. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
The del function is just to make it cleaner.
I tried with both an img in png and jpg, and it didn't open the img file.
I am on raspbian (maybe I should have stated that because I thought it was OS-dependent) but when I installed PIL it seemed to work perfectly.
print(img) doesn't write anything in the teminal.
The script is ran using python3 in the term.

Comment: So you ran `python3 YOURSCRIPT.py` from the Terminal in a directory where you can see your image listed if you run `ls -l pic.jpg` ?

Comment: 0

It may be that you don't have a default image viewer set. Try opening the image file outside of the program and see if it asks you to select a program or just opens in another program.

Comment: see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12570859/how-to-show-pil-images-on-the-screen/12571366

Comment: Yes that is how I open my script. I don't know I have no trouble opening an image on its own so that is not the viewer imo. Thanks for the link but I did look for answers elsewhere and the only way I found around it is to open the image in a webbrowser (through python)

Comment: Try adding `print(img)` on the line after opening it and reporting back the result.

Answer (score 0):

You can get some information to debug your Python by changing your code to the following:

```
from PIL import Image
import subprocess
import sys

# Print the full path of the Python interpreter you are using
print(sys.executable)

# Print the working directory that your program is running in
subprocess.run('pwd')

# Print directory listing
# WINDOWS VERSION: subprocess.run('DIR')
subprocess.run(['ls', '-l'])

# Open the image
img = Image.open("pic.jpg")

# Check image loaded and its size and type
print(img)

# Display image
img.show()

# Check program ran to completion
print('Done')
```