# How to make img.show() a blocking call in Pillow?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to see images as generated by the Python Imaging Library. Using the following snippet returns after displaying the image in a separate process. Is there a way to show images and have the python script block until I close the window?

```
from PIL import Image
...
img = Image.open(...)
img.show()
```

I could use a GUI library like Qt to achieve this. I don't want to add that just to view an image.

Comment: how are you running the process?

Comment: I'm running it like a normal python script. I want the script to block while I look at the image and then resume once I close the window.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8932976/python-imaging-library-show-on-windows

Comment: That's probably what I'm looking for! I'll give this a go tomorrow. Thanks! Why don't you this as an answer below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pillow explicitly starts its Mac and Unix Viewers in the background. Fortunately, Pillow also exposes a way to register custom viewers so you can override this behaviour.

I use `feh` personally:

```
import os
from PIL ImageShow


class FehViewer(ImageShow.UnixViewer):
    def show_file(self, filename, **options):
        os.system('feh %s' % filename)
        return 1

ImageShow.register(FehViewer, order=-1)

[...]
```

Answer (score 2):

An indirect way to achieve a blocking call is to show a PIL image in matplotlib:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import PIL

img = PIL.Image.open("image.jpg")
plt.imshow(np.asarray(img))
plt.show()    # Default is a blocking call
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple UI window using tk can accomplish this:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from tkinter import Tk, Label, BOTH
from tkinter.ttk import Frame, Style

class Example(Frame, object):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        label1 = Label(self)
        label1.photo= ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(r"myImage"))
        label1.config(image=label1.photo)
        label1.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        parent.mainloop()


Example(Tk())
```

Note: the code is in python 3, for python 2 the imports would be slightly different:

```
from Tkinter import Tk, Label, BOTH
from ttk import Frame, Style
```

Comment: This would work fine, but I would have to write quite a bit of GUI code in my python script.