# PIL Image display error in Windows 'It appears that the file was moved or renamed'

Tags: python, windows, python-imaging-library, bmp, photoviewer

I have just started using **PIL** in Python, and tried to open an image. Code below:

```
def openImage():
    
    PATH = input(f'Enter Path:\n> ')

    PATH = PATH.replace('"','')
    Image = I.open(PATH)

    OPEN = f'Opening image file at {PATH} ..'
    print(f'\n{OPEN}')

    Image.show()
```

It opened and appeared for a second but then this appeared:

> It appears that the file was moved or renamed

I googled for this error, only to realise that this happens with using PIL in Windows, since it converts it into a **temporary .bmp file** to open, and then it **gets deleted** as soon as the original one is closed, that's why the error.

Someone even asked the same question earlier [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40499524/pil-image-display-error-it-looks-like-the-image-was-moved-or-renamed) on StackOverflow, but no constructive solution was found.

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks in advance.