# When using Pillow for Python, when opening and showing an image, why does my code run indefinitely?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am working on a school coding project to learn how microservices work. I need to display an image based on a generated random number. I am using Pillow to display the image, by using a with block to open the image with Image.open and then showing the image. However, when I run this code, the image shows on my computer, but when I exit out of the image, my code is still running. How do I get it to stop executing code after it opens the image? It should close itself since I am using a with block I thought, so I'm not sure how to make it not run forever.

I tried manually closing the image after the .show() command with Pillow, and that still made the code run indefinitely. I currently have it formatted in a 'with' block, which should close itself, but it still runs indefinitely. I do not have any loops in my code, so it couldn't be an issue with a loop holding it up.

Comment: `.show()` opens an external program to display the image.  Pillow should be monitoring that program and continuing once it closes.  If it doesn't, that's a bug.  Which OS are you using, and do you know which program Pillow is opening?

Comment: @MarkRansom OS is Windows 10, and the program is Paint. I will try it on my home computer (I wrote it on my work computer, which only has Paint for viewing graphics) and see if opening it with a different Windows app fixes it.

Comment: I think there's a file you need to edit to get it to open in a different program.

Comment: Also see the opposite problem, Python continuing too quickly: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8932976/python-imaging-library-show-on-windows

Comment: @MarkRansom i tried to run the code on my home computer, and it runs properly with the windows photo app which isn't installed on my work computer. it must be an issue with it opening in paint. i'm curious as to why, but will have to do more digging into it after i finish the assignment. i appreciate your time to answer!